# BUG: Cannot vote again on post, even though there is no vote of mine currently applied

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On this post: [Format Currency string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094334/format-currency-string-to-integer)

I initially upvoted the first poster (Khalos), then I noticed that he used 'double' not 'decimal', so I undid that vote (within about 10 seconds).

I note now that he has updated his answer to use 'decimal', so I'd like to upvote him, but instead of being allowed to do that, I get:

> You last voted on this answer 34 mins
>   ago Your vote is now locked in unless
>   this answer is edited (click on this
>   box to dismiss)

Amusingly, it happens that this answer *was* edited, so this error message is wrong in two ways.

Clearly, when I view the post myself it does not show an orange upvote button (to indicate that I had, indeed, already voted).

-- Edit:

It might be worth noting that I have voted on a comment to the post (the posters own comment). It may be a bug on the logic/handling of this vote that is causing the issue.

-- Edit #2:

As usual, forays into the meta forum are a painful experience. I won't comment on this question further, but I leave it in place incase another person decides to report this bug.

Comment: I don't see any legitimate reason why we shouldn't be able to change votes in the first place.  This is a serious flaw in the design of the sites.

Answer (score -1):

If the poster made the edit in the 5 minute grace period, there is no formal edit recorded -- it is treated as if the post always existed that way.

Thus, your old vote cannot be changed because there was no edit.

Comment: You don't understand. I don't have a recorded vote on his post.

Comment: @silky the database says otherwise. You voted, then unvoted. These are counted.

Comment: So, in which direction is my vote indicated to me? It is neither a downvote or an upvote. Clearly, the implemention is wrong. You don't appear to accept this. That's fine. It doesn't change anything (i.e, from a usability/technical point of view the site is behaving incorrectly).

Comment: @silky this is necessary to prevent vote griefing and gaming of many types. Sorry. In the future, be more careful when casting your votes -- or earn 2k rep so you can edit the post and then re-vote as many times as you want.

Comment: so being careful is meant as to wait for the expiration of the 5 minute grace period before voting...

Comment: @carlos ~ I would say that is good advice anyways.

Comment: @Jeff So the suggested fix for a flaw designed to prevent abuse is to... abuse the system (edit a post solely for the purpose of revoting)? That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: There needs to be an "undo vote" feature that is distinct from "change vote". Or to put it another way, votes should have a grace period just like edits: if you undo it early enough *and* nobody else has made any changes on the question, then your undo will be a true "oops, I didn't mean to click there" fix, instead of a grudging "well, ok, but we're watching you" trap.